# What are the genders of the people listed in Nehemiah 8:4 and 8:7

Tags: law, gender

This might seem a little esoteric for my first question on this site, but it relates to some research I'm doing and I haven't found an answer among the resources I possess.

When Ezra reads out the Law to the people in Nehemiah 8:1-8, it explains that there were others standing there with him in front of the people (v4), as well as a number of others who read from the book of the Law and gave its sense so the people would understand the reading (v7-8). I recognise immediately that a number of the people listed are definitely male, but I do not know enough to ascertain the gender of all of them.

All of the following names are from the ESV translation:

v4: Mattithaiah, Shema, Anaiah, Uriah, Hilkiah, Maaseiah, Pedaiah, Mishael, Malchijah, Hashum, Hashbaddanah, Zechariah, Meshullam

v7: (Levites, therefore probably all male?) Jeshua, Bani, Sherebiah, Jamin, Akkub, Shabbethai, Hodiah, Maaseiah, Kelita, Azariah, Jozabad, Hanan, Pelaiah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all male names. You can check this through the use of Biblical encyclopedias and dictionaries that will list the uses of the name elsewhere in the Bible. A combination of Easton's Bible Dictionary and the ISBE would suffice. Examples of preliminary results for the first four names are as follows:

Mattithaia, male: (1 Chronicles 25:3, 21)
Shema, male: (1 Chronicles 8:13)
Anaiah, male: (Nehemiah 10:22)
Uriah, male: (1 Chronicles 11:41; 2 Samuel 23:39)

Comment: Ta. I should get myself a Bible encyclopedia!

Comment: @Gabriel - for matters like this, you can still use some of the very detailed [older Bible dictionaries and encyclopedia](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/3142/2215). FWIW.